# How to limit CPU usage while tar'ing a large file on a mounted NTFS partition?

Tags: mount, tar, cpu, ntfs, cpu-usage

I currently `tar -cvf` a 600gb folder, on the background, without compression.

I noticed that my ubuntu lags so much during this process, that it becomes practically unusable. When I `top` I see that

60% of my CPU is taken a `mount.ntfs` command and 15% of my CPU by the `tar`.

How can I limit the CPU usage of those two to let's say 30% and 10%, so that I can actually use my system at the same time?

Comment: You could use `nice` to set process scheduling. See `man nice` for more info.

Comment: Do you have a single core CPU?

Comment: `nice` could be useful too, but here it seems you need `ionice` because the perfomance degredation you see is probably more I/O usage related than CPU. Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437977/linux-extracting-tar-dramatically-slows-down-server

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov 8 core (i7), but still it lags

Comment: @thanasisp @panki I am "nicing" the tar command `nice -n 5 tar -cvf backup.tar backup/` , but still mount.ntfs seems to be unaffected.

Comment: try `ionice -c3 -p <pid>` for the pid of your process. It's not the CPU, it's the disk.

Comment: @thanasisp thanks - euharisto :)

Comment: `ionice` might not work in this instance since `mount.ntfs-3g` is a userspace process. Might make sense to re-ionice this process instead.

Comment: The `tar` process is to be re-ioniced, see also the related post above.

Comment: Artem, or you mean that, there could be any implications, over ntfs mount? In general, not for this case only, my simple thought is that if tar requesting is minimized, then this would be enough.

Comment: thanasis solution worked like fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slowdown is more probably caused by the disk usage rather than CPU usage. `tar` massively reads and writes for the 600G directory. See also related [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437977/linux-extracting-tar-dramatically-slows-down-server).

As the `tar` process is already running, you have to get its pid, using `pidof tar` or `ps aux | grep tar` and renice its I/O priority to class 3.

> -c, --class     name or number of scheduling class,
> 0: none, 1: realtime, 2: best-effort, 3: idle

```
ionice -c3 -p <pid>
```

This will also make the archiving take longer, as it will use the disk only when it is not being used by other programs.